# Multiple prompts for password when updating Visual Studio for Mac

Tags: macos, visual-studio, xamarin, visual-studio-mac

When updating Visual Studio for Mac, VS prompts me for an "administrator" password.

*That's fine.*

It does so several times.

*That's not that bad.*

It does so only when it gets to the point it needs it.

*That's bad.*

Why? Because that means I have to be keeping an eye on it for quite some time instead of `fire and forget`ing.

Is there any way around this?

Comment: And... how is this related to c# or xamarin?

Comment: Please see the following page to best report your issues with Xamarin: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/troubleshooting/support-options/